# Can we have multiple database instances on a Ruby project using Hanami?

Tags: ruby, hanami

Currently we have a single Aurora Postgresql db instance that we are interacting with but I would like to add one more db instance so that we can read from one database and write to another(existing one). We are using Hanami v1.3 and the project is in ruby.

I am trying to find documentation/resources on how to implement this and is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Hanami v1.3, checkout the following link:
https://github.com/hanami/hanami/issues/1028

Answer (score 0):

In hanami 2 (already in beta ) it is possible through rom-rb (you will love to work with it). I would not recommend to start a new project with hanami 1.3. I would go definitely with 2.0.